# Titanium ios failed to build on my test device

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

when I code :

```
ti build --platform ios --target device
```

I got this issue :

```
[TRACE]/usr/bin/touch -c /Users/wind/workspace/yuehouse/build/iphone/build/Debug-iphoneos/yuehouse.app.dSYM
[TRACE] ** BUILD SUCCEEDED **
[INFO]  Installing app on device: xxx iPhone
[ERROR] Failed to start "com.apple.syslog_relay" service (0xe800007f)
[ERROR] Project failed to build after 40s 884ms
[ERROR] Failed to start "com.apple.syslog_relay" service (0xe800007f)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just disable wifi on your device while building

Answer (score 2):

Try disable iTunes sync over Wi-Fi, it works for me.

Comment: This should have been a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 1):

That is a [well known bug](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-17595) which is still open.

[According to other users](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/177985/sdk-34-ios-install-on-device) it may help to reboot your phone and/or your Mac. Other users tried to install it several times and suddenly it worked. It could also help to unplug your phone and plug it in again.

Comment: user3904639 had the answer: disable wifi on the phone while building and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

-- This is from [TIMOB17595](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-17595?focusedCommentId=361680&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-361680)

(it just worked for me, perfectly)

Here's my workaround "ritual":

1- Unplug your device

2- Clean the project

3- Log out Appcelerator

4- Re-open Appcelerator and log in

5- Plug your device

6- Run the app

Comment: Define "Clean the project"